# Entity moving Up and Down but not Left and Right

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick

I am trying to create an entity class for my game but I'm having difficulty with the movement, I can get the sprite moving along the Y-Axis but not along the X-Axis.

Here's my code:-

```
package Game;

import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.geom.Rectangle;
import org.newdawn.slick.geom.Vector2f;

public class Entity {

    protected Vector2f pos; // Vector contains a value with components x & y
    protected Rectangle box;
    protected Image sprite;

    public Entity(float x, float y, int width, int height, Image sprite) {
        pos = new Vector2f(x,y);
        box = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        this.sprite = sprite;
    }

    public void update(GameContainer gc, int mapWidth, int mapHeight, int delta) {

    Vector2f trans = new Vector2f(0, 0);

    Input input = gc.getInput();

    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_W)) // Delta is used to move things on a frame rate independent way
        trans.y = -0.5f * delta;

    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_S))
        trans.y = 0.5f * delta;

    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_D))
        trans.x = 0.5f * delta;

    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_A))
        trans.x = -0.5f * delta;

    if (trans.x != 0 && trans.y != 0) { // If both components aren't null, we reduce them to have constant speed on all directions
        trans.set(trans.x / 1.5f, trans.y / 1.5f);
    }

    if(pos.x+trans.x > 32 && pos.x+trans.x < (mapWidth-64)) // Is the player inside the map? (We add (subtract) because of the stone wall)          pos.x += trans.x;               if(pos.y+trans.y &gt; 32 &amp;&amp; pos.y+trans.y &lt; (mapHeight-64))
        pos.y += trans.y;

}

public void render() {
    sprite.draw(pos.x, pos.y);
}

// Getters and Setters
public Vector2f getPos() {
    return pos;
}

public float getX() {
    return pos.x;
}

public float getY() {
    return pos.y;
}

public void setPos(Vector2f pos) {
    this.pos = pos;
}

public Rectangle getBox() {
    return box;
}

public void setBox(Rectangle box) {
    this.box = box;
}

public Image getSprite() {
    return sprite;
}

public void setSprite(Image sprite) {
    this.sprite = sprite;
}
}
```

I was just wondering if there's anything glaringly obvious as to why the sprite won't move left and right when the A & D keys are pressed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Too localized in my opinion. "Find my bug" questions are unlikely to help future visitors. See the [FAQ] about what types of questions to ask here. Good luck with your game.

Comment: I keep this in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(pos.x+trans.x > 32 && pos.x+trans.x < (mapWidth-64)) // Is the player inside the map? (We add (subtract) because of the stone wall)          pos.x += trans.x;               if(pos.y+trans.y &gt; 32 &amp;&amp; pos.y+trans.y &lt; (mapHeight-64))
        pos.y += trans.y;
```

That code will move the y component, but you seem to be missing moving x component

you have the correct code commented out right next to it. user error??